Django multi language
I want my Django site to be available in both English and Azerbaijani languages.
This is how I wrote the codes for it. However, I do not know what is true. Is there an alternative? Does this method affect the speed of the site?
in my view :
def change_Lang(request):
    referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') 
    lang = request.GET.get("pylang", "en")
    pylang = request.session.get("pylang", None) 
    if lang != "az" and lang != "en": lang = "en"
    if pylang == None: request.session["pylang"] = lang 
    if pylang != lang: request.session["pylang"] = lang 
    if referer: return HttpResponseRedirect(referer)
    return redirect("home")

in my templatetag:
@register.simple_tag
def pylang(value, en, az):
    if value == "en": return en
    elif value == "az": return az
    else: return en

in my template :
{% load pylang %}
{% pylang request.session.pylang "About - PyTerminator.com" "Haqqımızda - PyTerminator.com" %} 

I want to know if this method has a negative effect on the speed of the site?
What is the alternative?
Suggest better options. Thanks in advance)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The default way to do it, would be to use the built in localization i18n.
See the documentation. It boils down to writing
{% load i18n %} <!-- only once at the top -->

{% translate 'About' %}

<!-- or -->

{% blocktrans %}
Longer stuff
or even multiline
{% endblocktrans %}

in the templates and you will need no other code in the backend. You can also pass variables in the translations.
If you instead need (or want) to do translations within python code, you have to from django.utils.translation import gettext and call it with every string you want to translate e.g.
my_str = gettext("Hello")

my_str is now translated depending on the language.
You then call python manage.py makemessages --all to collect the Strings to translate.
The translation itself is then done via rosetta, which can be accessed in the browser.
Here all the strings in these translation blocks are collected and displayed, so you can provide translations in a form.
I just wanted to describe the basic workflow and wont go into detail. For set-up and the latter see the link given at the start.
I have no idea how the speed is affected.
